# Create Letters in C# and move them in Console

Tags: c#, console, letter

I need to create a Program where 'H' and 'S' are written as "#", move, change the size and do random colors on any letter. I must use Console.SetCursorPosition() but im not sure in which Position in the loop. i tried it in the for-loops but only moves a single line or not correctly.

[image: The Result must be like this]

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static int reihe, spalte;
    static int size;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HS();
    }

    static void H()
    {
        for (reihe = 0; reihe < 7; reihe++)
        {
            for (spalte = 0; spalte < 7; spalte++)
            {
                if ((spalte == 1 || spalte == 5) || (reihe == 3 && spalte > 1 && spalte < 6))
                {
                    Console.Write("#");
                }
                else
                {
                }

                Console.Write(" ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void S()
    {
        for (reihe = 0; reihe < 7; reihe++)
        {
            for (spalte = 0; spalte < 7; spalte++)
            {
                if (((reihe == 0 || reihe == 3 || reihe == 6) && spalte > 1 && spalte < 5) || (spalte == 1 && (reihe == 1 || reihe == 2 || reihe == 6)) || (spalte == 5 && (reihe == 0 || reihe == 4 || reihe == 5)))
                    Console.Write("#");
                else
                    Console.Write(" ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void HS()
    {
        //Erzeugt 7 Reihen
        for (reihe = 0; reihe < 7; reihe++)
        {
            //Erzeugt 13 Spalten
            for (spalte = 0; spalte < 13; spalte++)
            {
                //Erzeugt HS in einer if-Bedingung **FALSCH** Das H muss in einer Bedingung produziert werden wie das S in einer eigenen if-bedingung.
                if (((spalte == 1 || spalte == 5)

                    || (spalte == 8 && (reihe == 1 || reihe == 2 || reihe == 6)))

                    || (spalte == 12 && ( reihe == 0 || reihe == 4 || reihe == 5))

                    || (reihe == 3 && (spalte == 2 || spalte == 3 || spalte == 4 || spalte == 9 || spalte == 10 || spalte == 11))

                    || (reihe == 0 && (spalte == 9 || spalte == 10 || spalte == 11))

                    || (reihe == 6 && (spalte == 8 || spalte == 9 || spalte == 10 || spalte == 11)))
                {

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;   

                    Console.Write("#");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
    }

    static void HSUpdated()
    {
    }

    static void SwitchHS()
    {
        for (reihe = 0; reihe < 7; reihe++)
        {
            for (spalte = 0; spalte < 12; spalte++)
            {
                if (((reihe == 0) && (spalte > 0 && spalte < 5)) || ((spalte == 0) && (reihe > 0 && reihe < 3)) || ((reihe == 3) && (spalte > 0 && spalte < 4)) || ((spalte == 4) && (reihe > 3 && reihe < 6)) || ((reihe == 6) && (spalte < 4))) 
                {
                    Console.Write("#");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Console.SetCursorPosition()` in your `HS()` function. **Before** the `for` loop, if that doesn't work, put it in your `SwitchHS()` function.

Comment: it only moves a single line not the whole letter